# Include HTML file as embedded resource

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

A followup to another question I did, I've done some more digging but I am still coming up dry. Is there any way to include .HTML/.ASPX files as 'embedded resources' into an ASP.NET MVC application? I've found lots of examples of using string resources, but never other files entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it's possible.

Assuming that you want to use your embedded resource HTML/ASPX files as Views, you just need to:

1. Change the Build Action property to "Embedded Resource" on the files you want to embed as resources.
2. Write and register a custom [IViewEngine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iviewengine.aspx) to retrieve the resources. You can probably extend WebFormViewEngine and [WebFormView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.webformview.aspx) rather than starting from scratch, since you're basically just searching for the view markup in resources rather than on the file system.

Sounds like fun. Good luck!